AWS CloudWatch: cross region alarm notification aggregation
I have CloudWatch alarms across several different AWS accounts and several different Regions.
I would like all of these alarms' action notifications (e.g. "alarm X changed from state OK to In alarm") to populate a single SQS queue. Is there a way to do this without creating individual SNS topics/Lambda functions in each Region? I.e. in an ideal scenario, there could be a single topic/function which all the alarms could use for their alarm actions (based on my understanding though, this is impossible).
Note: I am aware that CloudWatch supports a cross-account cross-Region console to view alarms, metrics, etc. from other accounts/regions in a single Dashboard, but this is not what I am interested in. I am only interested in aggregating all of the alarm action notifications into a single queue, and the optimal way to do that.
Attempt: I have tried using the SNS topic in Region B for an alarm in Region A, and noticed that CloudWatch reports an error indicating that the regions cannot be different. I tried the same thing with a Lambda function and received a similar error during alarm creation.

There isn't an out-of-the-box way to do this but if you don't want to create and maintain Lambda functions, you could use this no-code approach.
CloudWatch alarms automatically publish events to EventBridge [1], so you could configure EventBridge rules in other regions to forward events you're interested in into the "aggregator" region [2]. And then, in the aggregator region, you could set up another rule with your SQS queue as a target [3].

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-and-eventbridge.html
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-cross-region.html
[3] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-targets.html

